# How to write unit test to assert the value of a jQuery element

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, qunit

I am using jQuery 1.4.1 and here is a simple code.

```
buildCol1: function() {
  var col = $('<select />', {className: 'col1' }).append($('<option />'));
  return $('<td />').append(col);
},
```

I am using qunit . In this case the method call is returning a jquery element. Since I am writing a test I should have something like

```
s = "<td><select class='col1'><option></option></select></td>"
```

I am not sure how do I get the fully expanded text value from a jquery element. I am sure I can get that by fully treaversing all the children. But I am hoping that there is an easier way to unit test this method.

Update:

After I posted the question I got an idea that on the returned element I can check for class name and for the right count of children. Basically this will be like inspecting the returned td to have right values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want to get the plain HTML source of a jQuery selection? The solution is to put it into a containing element and get that element's inner HTML:

```
var $myEl = $('<select />', {className: 'col1' }).append($('<option />'));
var src = $("<div></div>").append($myEl).html();
```